# Erase all numbers after a underscore

Tags: c#

I have this code which should erase all the numbers after a certain `_`

```
var fileNameOnly1 = Regex.Replace(fileNameOnly, @"[_\d]", string.Empty);
```

I.e.

**Input**

```
4a_32
abcdef43252_43242
```

**Current Output**

```
4a2
abcdef432523242
```

**Expected output**

```
4a
abcdef43252
```

I also tried using `@"[_\d]"`

is there any way to erase numbers after `_` and erase the '_' also ??

Comment: square brackets match any single character within, so you are matching for "an underscore or a digit", not "an underscore then a digit"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**Pattern**

```
_\d+
```

**Example**

```
var fileNameOnly = "asdads_234asd";
var result = Regex.Replace(fileNameOnly, @"_\d+", string.Empty);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

**Output**

```
asdadsasd
```

Comment: This exactly works for me, but I forgot to include the  _ , it should also be erased, my bad. What revision should work to remove _ also?

Comment: @NikkiMunoz update your question with the input and output again

Answer (score 2):

You dont specifically mention that you need to use regex and in most cases I would advise against it as regex is rather slow (comparison to other methods) and cumbersome (difficult to read and write).

I would think that it would be better to do this using string manipulation instead.

```
var fileNameOnly1 = fileNameOnly.Split('_')[0];
```

The above code will find the first '_' and take all characters before it (returned as a string).

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this regex:
`_\d+`

```
Regex.Replace(fileNameOnly, @"_\d+", string.Empty);
```